# Trying to write my revenue report into a .txt file

Tags: python

I made two separate files. This is my first file:

```
def revenue_report():
    revenue1 = float(input("Enter revenue for month 1: "))
    revenue2 = float(input("Enter revenue for month 2: "))
    revenue3 = float(input("Enter revenue for month 3: "))
    sum2 = revenue1 + revenue2
    sum3 = revenue1 + revenue2 + revenue3
    print(f'''
Revenue Report
--------------------------''')
    print("Revenue for 1: $     {:,.2f} | Cumm. Total: $     {:,.2f}".format(revenue1, revenue1))
    print("Revenue for 2: $     {:,.2f} | Cumm. Total: $     {:,.2f}".format(revenue2, sum2))
    print("Revenue for 3: $     {:,.2f} | Cumm. Total: $     {:,.2f}".format(revenue3, sum3))
    print("The company has made a total of ${:,} in revenue in the past quarter.".format(sum3))
```

As for my second file, I'm supposed to import the function from the first file and then make changes to the function so that it receives input file name from caller to print the
revenue report into a text file. Then I need to call the revenue report function to obtain
a quarter’s revenues from user, and finally print out the report to a text file.

My second file:

```
import Task63a

filename = "revenue_report.txt"
file = open(filename, "w")
data = str(Task63a.revenue_report())
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

However this gives me a revenue_report.txt file that has None in it. Why is that so? Explanation in beginner's terms would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return any value. If a function in python does not return anything it returns always None.

You can create a text variable and add new lines to this variable. Then you have to return your variable.

```py
def return_string():
    txt = "Line 1\n"
    txt += "Line 2\n"
    return txt
```

The "\n"are the line endings, this makes it possible for each line to start on a new line in the text-file.

I think it will look like this, but I did not test it:

```py
def revenue_report():
    revenue1 = float(input("Enter revenue for month 1: "))
    revenue2 = float(input("Enter revenue for month 2: "))
    revenue3 = float(input("Enter revenue for month 3: "))
    sum2 = revenue1 + revenue2
    sum3 = revenue1 + revenue2 + revenue3
    txt = 'Revenue Report\n--------------------------')
    txt += "Revenue for 1: $     {:,.2f} | Cumm. Total: $     {:,.2f}\n".format(revenue1, revenue1)
    txt += "Revenue for 2: $     {:,.2f} | Cumm. Total: $     {:,.2f}\n".format(revenue2, sum2)
    txt += "Revenue for 3: $     {:,.2f} | Cumm. Total: $     {:,.2f}\n".format(revenue3, sum3)
    txt += "The company has made a total of ${:,} in revenue in the past quarter.".format(sum3))
    return txt
```